# PHP's move_uploaded_file advice

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm having real problems with the PHP `move_uploaded_file` command to work properly on a shared Apasche web hosting server.

If I want to create a folder (`mkdir`) I have to use the full path name, e.g.

```
$target_path = "/home/myhostingname/public_html/uploads/files/".$lastID;
mkdir($target_path, 0755);
```

That works, the unique folder is created and using FileZilla I can upload files to it.

However when I try and use the full path with the `move_uploaded_file` command nothing ever gets uploaded. E.g.

```
move_uploaded_file($tmp_file, $target_path);
```

where, e.g. :

```
$tmp_file = "/home/myhostingname/public_html/tmp/php8MR5Qv/test.gif"
$target_path = "/home/myhostingname/public_html/uploads/files/130/"
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong. The script is accepted but there would appear to be a mismatch going on...

Comment: Does it work if you use full access to the folder: `0777`?

Comment: it should work if you are creating the folder from php script. then it will be owned by your www-unix-user, the user who has initially started the webserver. creating a folder via ftp and then writing to it, requires higher then a 5-hex on the 3rd/4th - as the owner may be a different one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File from `$tmp_file` should be uploaded via HTTP POST request, otherwise `move_uploaded_file` will not work.

To check if file has been uploaded use `is_uploaded_file`

So your code might look like this:

```
$tmp_file = "/home/myhostingname/public_html/tmp/php8MR5Qv/test.gif"
$target_path = "/home/myhostingname/public_html/uploads/files/".$lastID;
if(is_uploaded_file($tmp_file)){
    mkdir($target_path, 0755);
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_file, $target_path);
}
```

Comment: I think you've struck on the problem in that the tmp file doen't appear to be there, even though it's giving me a path and unique has (?) every time. I have tried it in the absolute and local path but no joy. What do I do next?

Comment: @EdwardHasted how did you put in there this file? Is it uploaded via HTTP POST? Is it exists and if so - does it have enough permissions?

Answer (score 0):

The solution appears to be that the $target_path is actually a file. The documentation doesn't make that particularly clear. However when you start finding code that works the desitination is a path and filename... When I made this change it worked immediately.